# Как вводить значения через командную строку?

Tags: c, командная-строка

```
**Код меняет местами два указанных байта числа. Т.е запрашивается число,
первое число, второе число. Но нужно, чтобы все это вводилось через
конмадную строку, используя atoi(argv[]). Как это сделать?**

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long number;
    int f_pl, s_pl;
    printf("Input the number: ");
    scanf("%llu", &number);
    printf("\nInput the first byte place(left to right):");
    scanf("%d", &f_pl);
    printf("\nInput the second byte place: ");
    scanf("%d", &s_pl);
    func(number, f_pl, s_pl);
    return 0;
}

int func(unsigned long long number, int f_pl, int s_pl){
    unsigned long long mask_previous=255;
    unsigned long long mask_1, mask_2;
    unsigned long long ilon_Mask;
    unsigned long long ne_Mask, new_number;

    mask_1 = mask_previous << (8*f_pl);
    mask_2 = mask_previous << (8*s_pl);
    ilon_Mask = mask_1 | mask_2;
    ne_Mask = ~ilon_Mask;
    mask_1 = number & mask_1;
    mask_2 = number & mask_2;
    mask_1 = mask_1 << (8*(s_pl-f_pl));
    mask_2 = mask_2 >> (8*(s_pl-f_pl));
    ilon_Mask = mask_1 | mask_2;
    ne_Mask = number & ne_Mask;
    new_number = ilon_Mask | ne_Mask;
    printf("%llu", new_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Если так, то вообще ничего не выводит..............................

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
 {
    unsigned f_pl, s_pl, number, new_number;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    if (argc == 4)
    {
        f_pl = atoi(argv[1]);
        s_pl = atoi (argv [2]);
        number = atoi(argv[3]);
        new_number = func(f_pl,s_pl, number);
        printf("New number:  %d\n", new_number);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Input error!\n");

    }
}

int func(int f_pl, int s_pl, unsigned long long number){
    unsigned long long mask_previous=255;
    unsigned long long mask_1, mask_2;
    unsigned long long ilon_Mask;
    unsigned long long ne_Mask, new_number;

    mask_1 = mask_previous << (8*f_pl);
    mask_2 = mask_previous << (8*s_pl);
    ilon_Mask = mask_1 | mask_2;
    ne_Mask = ~ilon_Mask;
    mask_1 = number & mask_1;
    mask_2 = number & mask_2;
    mask_1 = mask_1 << (8*(s_pl-f_pl));
    mask_2 = mask_2 >> (8*(s_pl-f_pl));
    ilon_Mask = mask_1 | mask_2;
    ne_Mask = number & ne_Mask;
    new_number = ilon_Mask | ne_Mask;
    printf("%llu", new_number);
    return new_number;
}
```

что было до этого, работало правильно 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас вот что выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Собственно `number = atol(argv[1]; f_pl = atoi(argv[2]);` и т.п. в  зависимости от порядка параметров. И перед этим не помешало бы проверить в argc, что вам в принципе передали нужное кол-во параметров

Answer (score 0):

Для ввода значений через командную строку нужно при запуске программы после имени исполняемого файла указать через пробелы эти значения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получить эти значения можно с помощью аргументов функции `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. `argc` - это количество переданных аргументов. `argv` - массив строк, который содержит переданные аргументы.

Заметьте, что имя программы (в данном случае `./prog`) тоже является таким аргументом, поэтому `argc` будет на 1 больше, чем количество переданных вами аргументов.

Соответственно:

```
argc == 4
argv[0] == "./progc"  // Это формальная запись. Строки надо сравнивать не так.
argv[1] == "1000"
argv[2] == "1"
argv[3] == "2"
argv[4] == NULL
```

Стоит ещё отметить, что массив argv всегда заканчивается значением `NULL`.

Comment: не получается, добавила выше код

Comment: может, я неправильно передаю получившееся новое число new_number в функции func() ???

Comment: @АлияГафурова, у вас это вообще не должно компилироваться, потому как func объявляется ниже, чем main.

Comment: изменила, не помогло

Comment: @АлияГафурова, как вы запускаете?

Comment: добавила выше...............

Comment: Вы уверены, что запускаете нужный исполняемый файл. Программа должна выводить что-то.

Comment: да, изменила выше

Comment: я не понимаю, ну чтоо неправильно...

Comment: я правильно передаю полученное число в main???

Comment: Задайте лучше новый вопрос с вашей проблемой